# How to find matches in mongodb for all elements in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to attempt to search all matches in the mongodb database that I have created for each of the different elements in an array. I have the following code

```
var fiatList = ['EUR', 'AUD', 'BRL', 'CAD', 'CHF', 'CNY', 'CZK', 'DKK'];

function updateFiatTotal() {

    fiatList.forEach(function(entry){
    console.log('Calculating Fiat total data');
    models.Market.find({ quote: { $in: entry } }, function(err, markets) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('markets');
     });
  });
}
```

For some reason this is not returning anything for the markets that I am trying to print out into the database. If anyone could give me pointers on why it is not correctly querying the mongodb database it would be apprecaited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$in` expects an array, so you'd have to pass the fiatList as parameter. That is, if you are looking for a document where `quote: ['EUR', 'AUD', 'BRL', 'CAD', 'CHF', 'CNY', 'CZK', 'DKK']`

```
models.Market.find({
    quote: fiatList
}, function(err, markets) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('markets');

});
```

Now if you are looking for a document that could have one of these values. Example: `quote:['EUR', 'AUD'], quote:['CZK', 'CHF']`
Then you could do this:

```
fiatList.forEach(function(entry) {

    models.Market.find({
        quote: entry
    }, function(err, markets) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('markets');

    });
});
```

This way you could get the same document if `quote:['CZK', 'CHF']`, cause you would get it once for

```
models.Market.find({
    quote: 'CZK'
})
```

and once for

```
models.Market.find({
    quote: 'CHF'
})
```

Also if you still don't get any results, check if your collection is called **market** instead of **Market**. I've heard before that people created the collection in mongoose with capital but in mongodb it was written lowercase.

Comment: So quote is an array, How would I find all entries in the quote array?

Comment: So quote is an array, How would I find all entries for each of the elements in the quote array if there are multiple matches for each element in quote for the quote in the fiatList?

Comment: yea so I am trying to find all entries in the quote array for each of the entries in the fiatlist. So for example I want to add up all of the quotes where it equals 'EUR' and then add the values all together, then check all entries in the fiatlist where quote equals 'AUD', etc.

Comment: Ok, hold on. Aggregating results is another thing. Your problem was that you don’t get any results at all from your query. So I suppose it didn’t work with any of my suggestions?